# angular opaque error Circular dependency in DI detected

Tags: angular

Hi I'm using angular 14 code and this error is happening during a migration work from angular 9 .
a weird circular dependency error is happening like below despite there is no real dependency between the indicated files in the attached error console below: please give me a tip about how to debug this error , it seems to be related to some initialization process of the app and I don't know where to look at all .
[image]

code of the different files are :
configurationAppService

```
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/common';
import {Inject, Injectable, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {EnvironmentContext} from "../models/core/environment-context";
import {ConfigurationApp} from "../models/core";
import {EnvManagementService} from "./env-management.service";
import {filter} from "rxjs/operators";
import {first} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConfigurationAppService {
  private envConf = {} as ConfigurationApp;

  private envContext: EnvironmentContext;

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) document: HTMLDocument,
    private envManagementService: EnvManagementService
  ) {
    this.envManagementService.env.pipe(first(),filter(newEnv => newEnv !== null))
      .subscribe( (envValue: EnvironmentContext) => {
        this.envContext = envValue;
      });
  }


  get fullenvContext(): EnvironmentContext {
    return this.envContext;
  }

  get defaultProfileId(): number {
    return this.envContext.profileId;
  }

  getConfigValue(key: string) {
    return this.envConf[key];
  }

  get fullConfiguration() {
    return this.envConf;
  }

  get prefixAsset() {
    return this.envConf.prefixAsset;
  }

  get debug() {
    return this.envConf.debug === true;
  }

  set debug(debug: boolean) {
    this.envConf.debug = debug;
  }

  get codeBrique() {
    return this.envConf.codeBrique;
  }

  get codeQuartier() {
    return this.envConf.codeQuartier;
  }

  get origin() {
    return this.envConf.origin;
  }

  get baseHref() {
    return this.envConf.baseHref;
  }

  get privateOffice() {
    return this.envConf.privateOffice;
  }

  set privateOffice(privateOffice: boolean) {
    this.envConf.privateOffice = privateOffice;
  }

  get logLevel() {
    return this.envConf.logLevel;
  }

  set logLevel(logLevel) {
    this.envConf.logLevel = logLevel;
  }


  get cas() {
    return this.envConf.cas;
  }

}
```

global-error-handler.service.ts

```
import {ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector} from '@angular/core';

import {LoggerService} from 'webrc-lib-angular-module';

/**
 * Handler global des erreurs.
 */
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    constructor(private readonly _injector: Injector) {}

    private get logger() {
        return this._injector.get(LoggerService);
    }

    /**
     * Afficher une erreur générique à la console
     * @param error erreur à traiter
     */
    public handleError(error: any) {
        this.logger.error(error);
    }
}
```

logger.Service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';


import {ConfigurationAppService} from './configuration.app.service';
import {LogLevel} from "../models/core";


const noLog = () => undefined;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoggerService {
  private level: LogLevel;

  constructor(private readonly configurationAppService: ConfigurationAppService) {
    const configuration = configurationAppService;
    if (configuration.debug) {
      this.level = LogLevel.DEBUG;
    } else {
      if (configuration.logLevel) {
        if (typeof configuration.logLevel === 'string') {
          if (LogLevel[configuration.logLevel]) {
            this.level = LogLevel[configuration.logLevel];
          } else {
            this.level = LogLevel.WARN;
            console.warn('[WARN]', 'Niveau de log non valide dans la configuration => passage en mode WARN');
          }
        } else if (typeof configuration.logLevel === 'number') {
          if (LogLevel[configuration.logLevel]) {
            this.level = configuration.logLevel;
          } else {
            this.level = LogLevel.WARN;
            console.warn('[WARN]', 'Niveau de log non valide dans la configuration => passage en mode WARN');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  get debug() {
    return LogLevel.DEBUG <= this.level ? console.log.bind(console, '[DEBUG]') : noLog;
  }

  get info() {
    return LogLevel.INFO <= this.level ? console.log.bind(console, '[INFO]') : noLog;
  }

  get warn() {
    return LogLevel.WARN <= this.level ? console.log.bind(console, '[WARN]') : noLog;
  }

  get error() {
    return LogLevel.ERROR <= this.level ? console.error.bind(console, '[ERROR]') : noLog;
  }
}
```